# Odoo one2many field value is being written two times

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-9

What I've got is simple one to many field and one Html field which is computed when one2many field is being changed.

```py
requirements = fields.One2many('cust.req', 'templ_id')
comment = fields.Html(compute='do_smth')

@api.depends('requirements')
def do_smth(self)
    ....
```

What happens is: When I fill one2many field and click save everything is fine. But in my form I also have button 'view' which passes some field values to other form and opens it.

```py
 template_comment = self.env['customer.comment.v'].search([('tmpl_id','=',self.id)])
 return {
            'name': _('Customer Req Comments'),
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'res_model': 'customer.comment.v',
            'view_type': 'form',
            'view_mode': 'form',
            'view_id': 
            self.env.ref('tmpl_data.magnus_order_tmpl_comment_form').id,
            'target': 'new',
            'res_id': new_comment.id,
        }
```

So let's say I already have One2many field filled with three lines before. Then I come back to my form add additional 4th line, click button view to open other form, then close that form and save parent form, additional 4th record will be duplicated. I think that this happens because when I click random button 'view' write method is called one and when I click save button, write method is called once again with same value. So in the end additional line(s) is duplicated.

My question is how do I avoid something like that happening?
Thank you for your time!!

Comment: I am sure there is some method which contains an error so that the execution stopped and when you again click on the button it will again save so, you are getting duplicate lines. please check the stack trash is there any error while doing this transactions?

Comment: Nop. no errors. He simple calls write method two times, as I said, one on View button, then write method is called on save button. Both write methods contains value that I added to line.

Comment: Actually. in can even duplicate tons of times. Simply whenever I click button, line elements that were added duplicates.. So If  I click View button three times it will duplicate three times...

Comment: Did you raised any exception in the view button or only return the action? because i have the same duplicate when i raise the exception in any button and then save.

Comment: Nop I simply check if record with certain data exists at other table, than return form with that record, of if it doesn't exist I create new record and then return form, that's it...

Comment: I created same view as you said but i am not getting duplicate. it only duplicating when i raise any exception in it and then save.But i will be back to you soon if i have any hint on it.

Comment: Probably you are not getting duplicates because when you return new view you use 'target': 'current' or 'target': 'self'. But when you add one record and click button which targets 'new' (pop up), then it duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

In the same method you should go to your class in the other view and use these.

## here is the code

```
`x_line = self.env['customer.comment.v']`
`x_delete = x_line.search([('tmpl_id','=',self.id)]).unlink()`
```

`x_delete` will delete the previous registrations if they are the same.